# Camel: RabbitMQ to SOAP : requeue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, apache-camel, integration

I am learning Apache camel and trying to send request from RabbitMQ endpoint to some soap service :

```
<camelcontext>
route 1 from file:// to rabbitmq queue 
<route id="2">
<from uri="same queue as in route 1"/>
<process "here i am setting header "/>
<pattern>InOut</pattern>
<to uri="soap request"/>
</camelcontext>
```

What I want is that in case there is any exception at SOAP, exchange should be requeued back to rabbitmq. **I have tried setting header of exchange rabbitmq.REQUEUE to true still no luck, message gets removed even though there is exception. I have tried setting exchange to InOUT too.** Please suggest any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To catch an exception coming back from calling the SOAP service you could use an onException to catch the fault and then route it to rabbitMQ queue like this:

```
onException(Fault.class).handled(true)
    .to("rabbitmq:queue-name")
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is different from what I want. This will send message to the end of the queue. I want it to just go back in the sense that it should go back to same position i.e. start of queue not end